# Parallel threads with TensorFlow Dataset API and flat_map

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm changing my TensorFlow code from the old queue interface to the new [Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset). With the old interface I could specify the `num_threads` argument to the `tf.train.shuffle_batch` queue. However, the only way to control the amount of threads in the Dataset API seems to be in the `map` function using the `num_parallel_calls` argument. However, I'm using the `flat_map` function instead, which doesn't have such an argument.

**Question**: Is there a way to control the number of threads/processes for the `flat_map` function? Or is there are way to use `map` in combination with `flat_map` and still specify the number of parallel calls?

Note that it is of crucial importance to run multiple threads in parallel, as I intend to run heavy pre-processing on the CPU before data enters the queue.

There are two ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7951#issuecomment-305796971) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7951#issuecomment-326098305)) related posts on GitHub, but I don't think they answer this question.

Here is a minimal code example of my use-case for illustration:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    data = tf.ones(shape=(10, 512), dtype=tf.float32, name="data")
    input_tensors = (data,)

    def pre_processing_func(data_):
        # normally I would do data-augmentation here
        results = (tf.expand_dims(data_, axis=0),)
        return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(results)

    dataset_source = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input_tensors)
    dataset = dataset_source.flat_map(pre_processing_func)
    # do something with 'dataset'
```

Comment: Kind of a clunky workaround, but how about using `map()` with your preprocessing function, then `prefetch()` to buffer items and finally `flat_map()` with a `lambda x : x` function that takes care of flattening?

Comment: @GPhilo That idea seems to work indeed, not sure if there is any overhead anywhere. Do you want to give this as an answer, i.e.:

`pre_processing_func` no longer returning a dataset and using a regular map on it, followed by a `dataset.flat_map(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x))`

Comment: Good to hear that it helped. I'll write a small full-code example as an answer.

Comment: I have a question though, is it your intended use-case to have one `Dataset` instance for each sample? It looks extremely confusing to me, as typically you'd have only one `Dataset` instance that produces batches.

Comment: No, one Dataset in total. In the example posted here I would have 10 input vectors with 512 elements each. Then, in `pre_processing_func` I would apply data-augmentation, generating a random amount of vectors of 512 for each input. In the example there is no randomness, but always returns 1 sample for 1 input, simulated by the `tf.expand_dims`.

Comment: Oh I see! Now it's clear, thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, at the moment `flat_map` does not offer parallelism options.
Given that the bulk of the computation is done in `pre_processing_func`, what you might use as a workaround is a parallel `map` call followed by some buffering, and then using a `flat_map` call with an identity lambda function that takes care of flattening the output.

In code:

```python
NUM_THREADS = 5
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000

def pre_processing_func(data_):
    # data-augmentation here
    # generate new samples starting from the sample `data_`
    artificial_samples = generate_from_sample(data_)
    return atificial_samples

dataset_source = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input_tensors).
                  map(pre_processing_func, num_parallel_calls=NUM_THREADS).
                  prefetch(BUFFER_SIZE).
                  flat_map(lambda *x : tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)).
                  shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)) # my addition, probably necessary though
```

#### Note (to myself and whoever will try to understand the pipeline):

Since `pre_processing_func` generates an arbitrary number of new samples starting from the initial sample (organised in matrices of shape `(?, 512)`), the `flat_map` call is necessary to turn all the generated matrices into `Dataset`s containing single samples (hence the `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)` in the lambda) and then flatten all these datasets into one big `Dataset` containing individual samples.

It's probably a good idea to `.shuffle()` that dataset, or generated samples will be packed together.

Comment: Minor suggestion: make the lambda accept `*x` instead of `x` to make it generic for the case of multiple inputs (e.g. data and labels). Aside from this, one problem I have with your suggestion is that the `prefetch` is before the `flat_map`. Is that really needed? Because now the buffer-size is not the actual buffer-size, but the amount of inputs (which might result in a variable number of items in the buffer finally). Is there a way around this?

Comment: I updated the lambda as suggested (or at least I hope, I'm not super confident wit generic arguments). About the prefetch, it is necessary if you want to have the threads running in parallel. I don't have specifics on the implementation of `map`, but from what I understood, unless you put a buffer after it, the threads will hang until the value they produce is consumed. Indeed, the prefetch counts "items", which at that stage is not samples, but the matrices with the artificial samples. You can trigger that value as needed (1000 is probably way too high).

Comment: The actual samples buffer, however, is the one in `shuffle` (which, if you don't want to have shuffling, can be replaced by another `prefetch()`).

Comment: As I said, for me this buffer size is meaningless, since one input could produce anywhere in the range of 1 to 1000 inputs. But anyway I've put the `prefetch` after the `flat_map` and it seems to run in parallel, I tested with a small sample. And also according to your reasoning, the output of `map` would be directly consumed by `flat_map`, which would directly go into the `prefetch` buffer afterwards, right? I think the question is solved, thanks.

Comment: That buffer size should not be interpreted as the number of samples stored in the buffer. That's the number of *results* from `map` that can be stored before stalling the threads. And no, the threads in `map` stall until their output is consumed, before starting with a new sample. They get directly consumed only if flat_map is fast enough to process 5 outputs before one map thread produces a new output. Since this is very likely the case, you get a speedup. In the end, the difference is minimal and if i works for you, no need to complicate things ;)

Comment: Yes, I understand that about the buffer size. That's why I'm saying that it has no meaning to me in my use-case, I would need to be able to set it for the actual number of samples. But I can do that by putting the buffer afterwards. About the stalling, do you mean it stalls at the end? Because I did a test with a long bogus `tf.while_loop` in the above example in pre-processing and I do see N threads starting them. Afterwards the `flat_map` is very lightweight anyway (just a copy/move), so I'm quite convinced `map` won't stall in my use-case.

Comment: @GPhilo, great example. In `generate_from_sample(data_)`, `data_` is a tensor, whereas I need the actual value to process. What is the ideal way to code up a function like `generate_from_sample` which reads a file based on `data_` passed and returns processed contents of the file. `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["filename1", "filename2"])...`

Comment: @Nitin it's probably better if you open a new question and possibly reference this one mentioning how your use-case is different.. I didn't quite get the specific problem you have from your description. If you do open a question, put a link here and I'll take a look as soon as I get a chance :)

Comment: @GPhilo, thank you. I created a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179857/parallelize-tf-from-generator-using-tf-contrib-data-parallel-interleave