# Parallelize tf.from_generator using tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have a bunch of JSON array files (AVRO to be accurate) and each of them yield multiple samples for training a Keras Model. Using ideas from [@GPhilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47414078/1585523) and from [@jsimsa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47874044/1585523), I was able to come up with this to parallelize my input pipeline. Unable to figure out how to design the `generator(n)` to divide the work of processing files. The code fails inside `parse_file(f)` as the function expects a string file path and not a `Tensor`,

```
N = num_cores = 2
files_to_process = ["f1.avro", "f2.avro", "f3.avro"]
shuffle_size = prefetch_buffer = 1000
batch_size = 512

def generator(n):
    size = math.ceil(len(files_to_process) / N)
    start_index = n * size
    end_index = start_index + size

    def gen():
        # for f in files_to_process[start_index:end_index]:
        for f in tf.slice(files_to_process, start_index, size):
            yield f

    return gen

def dataset(n):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator(n), (tf.string,))

def process_file(f):
    examples_x, examples_y = parse_file(f)
    return examples_x, examples_y

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(N)
ds = ds.apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(dataset, cycle_length=N))
ds = ds.map(process_file, num_parallel_calls=N)
ds = ds.prefetch(prefetch_buffer)
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda *x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x))
ds = ds.batch(batch_size).shuffle(shuffle_size)

...
myTfKerasModel.fit( ds.make_one_iterator(), NUM_TRAIN_SAMPLES // batch_size )
```

- What is the correct way to design `generator(n)` here
- Is this an optimized way to design my input pipeline using `parallel_interleave` and `flat_map`

Comment: Have you checked already [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func)?

Comment: Using `tf.py_func` surfaced `Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn`, I think for `generator(n)`. Not sure how to design a generator using tensors. Also `tf.py_func`'s limitations are also worrying a little bit. Is there a better way to design `generator()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me you're complicating your life unnecessarily with the generator.
This is how I'd implement your input pipeline:

```
def parse_file_tf(filename):
    return tf.py_func(parse_file, [filename], [tf.float32, tf.float32])

# version with map
files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files_to_process)
dataset = files.map(parse_file_tf, num_parallel_calls=N)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda *x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).shuffle(shuffle_size).prefetch(2)
it = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

To test it, I define a dummy `parse_file` as:

```
i=0
def parse_file(f):
    global i
    i += 1
    return np.asarray([i]*i, dtype=np.float32), np.asarray([i]*i, dtype=np.float32) # mimicks variable-length examples_x, examples_y
```

which I feed into a basic loop that shows what the iterator returns:

```
sess = tf.Session()
try:
    while True:
        x, y = it.get_next()
        vx, vy = sess.run([x,y])
        print(vx)
        print(vy)
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    pass
sess.close()
```

Running the code above prints:

```
[2. 3. 2. 1. 3. 3.]
[2. 3. 2. 1. 3. 3.]
```

#### Explanation of the pipeline

Essentially, I leave the parallelization issue to `map`, where I can pass the number of threads it should run. No need for generators iterating over ranges and those extra complications.

I chose map over `parallel_interleave` because the latter requires you to generate a `Dataset` instance for each item it returns, which in your case doesn't really make sense because you already have loaded all values in memory when you run `parse_file`.
`parallel_interleave` makes sense if you slowly generate the values (e.g., by applying `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` to a list of filenames), but if your dataset fits in memory go for `map`.

About the `tf.py_func` limitations, they do not affect your trained network, only the input pipeline. Ideally, you'll have a different pipeline for your training and for your final use of the network. You only need to take care of the limitations during the latter, while for training (unless you do something very specific with distributed training and/or moving the training across machines) you're reasonably safe.

---

#### Version with Generator

If your JSON files are very big and their content won't fit in memory, you can use a generator, but slightly different from the approach you began with.
The idea is, the generator goes through the JSON file and `yield`s one record at a time. Then, the generator has to be your `parse_file` function. As an example, let's assume you have the following `parse_file` generator:

```
i = 3
def parse_file(filename):
    global i
    i += 1
    ctr = 0
    while ctr < i:
        yield ctr, ctr
```

In this case, the pipeline would look as follows:

```
def wrap_generator(filename):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(parse_file(filename), [tf.int32, tf.int32])

files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files_to_process)
dataset = files.apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(wrap_generator, cycle_length=N))
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda *x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_size).batch(batch_size).prefetch(2)
it = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Note that here we need to use `parallel_interleave` because we turn the generators into `Dataset` instances from which we extract values.
The rest stays the same.

Feeding this to the same sample loop as above prints:

```
[6. 5. 4. 4. 6. 5. 6. 6. 5. 4. 6. 4. 5. 5. 6.]
[6. 5. 4. 4. 6. 5. 6. 6. 5. 4. 6. 4. 5. 5. 6.]
```

Comment: amazing explanations and ideas. Simple and elegant! In the generator version, I think you meant `files.apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(wrap_generator, cycle_length=N))` after fetching the files. Chose the generator approach so that the model need not wait until entire file is read - i.e. data prep and training can go in parallel.

In order to test this hypothesis and finding the right settings for these APIs (like cycle_length etc), is there a way to visualize - % time spent in CPU and % time spent in IO for a run, something like this https://youtu.be/SxOsJPaxHME?t=977?

Comment: Right! Yes, indeed I had left a wrong line for `files.apply(...)`, thanks for catching it, I fixed it in the code now ;) I am not aware of any visualization tools for input pipeline performance, I know it's an area where TF's team has been working for a while, but that's all I know for sure. Tips on how to improve your input pipelines are available here: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance

Comment: Or you know of any profiling tools which can print these numbers?
(1) % time in CPU
(2) % time in IO for a run

Comment: Take a look here if this might be helpful: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/README.md

Comment: yeah wrapped the `model.fit()` as shown in the question inside `with tf.contrib.tfprof.ProfileContext('/tmp/train_dir') as pctx:` block but it doesn't seem to log anything. I wanted this as the training this way is slower than earlier sequential approach - `fetch batch -> prepare batch -> train batch`. Guessing that there are too many context switches.